Combining Suspense fallback and loading fallback in React
I have a component in React and I have created a skeleton for this component. This component also makes an api call to get data which is to be shown in this component. I have lazy loaded the component and provided skeleton as fallback. I also want to show the skeleton while the api call is in progress.
function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton />}>
      <Component />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function Component() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetchData()
      .then((data) => {
        setApiData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if(isLoading) {
    return <Skeleton />;
  }
  return <div>{apiData}</div>;
}```


Is there any way of combining both suspense fallback and loading fallback? I feel like the way i am doing it is not right and there might be a better way of handling this type of solution.

